# What's the correct way to add objects via the `has_many through:` association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many

I would like to better understand how the `has_many through:` association works on Rails 4.0.

Let's say I have these models:

```
class Parent
  has_many :parent_sons
  has_many :sons, through: :parent_sons
end

class Son
  has_many :parent_sons
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_sons
end

class ParentSon
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :son
  validates :son, presence: true
  validates :parent, presence: true
end
```

Now, if I go into the console and create a couple of test objects, associating parents and sons via the `has_many through:` definition, I obtain this:

```
a = Parent.new
b = Son.new
a.sons << b
a.valid?
=> false

# The ParentSon object has a Son but no Parent:
c = a.parent_sons.first
c.son
=> b
c.parent
=> nil
```

The same behavior occurs if I type

```
a.parent_sons.build(son: b)
```

instead of doing `a.sons << b`.

So, apparently, the correct association has been created between the `ParentSon` object and the `Son` object, but not between `ParentSon` and `Parent`, which is the object I attached the `Son` to.

Similarly, if I do

```
b.parents << a
```

I will obtain a relation between `ParentSon` and `Parent` but not with the original `Son`.

Obviously this is breaking the validation in the `ParentSon` object, since one of the two outgoing relations is always missing.

So, what's the correct way to append an *existing* object with a `has_many through:` association without breaking this kind of validations?

#### Edit

This behavior is breaking my rspec tests too. Using the `factory_girl` gem this way:

```
factory :parent do
  after(:create) do |p|
    p.sons << FactoryGirl.create(:son)
  end
end
```

The object created via `FactoryGirl.create(:parent)` will not pass the validation for the same reason, since it has a `ParentSon` object with a correct `Son` reference but an empty `Parent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that when using `has_many through:` the only way to properly add relations to `Parent` using an existing `Son` object is to completely define the joining object details.

Eg.

```
a.parent_sons.build(parent: a, son: b)
```

is the right way to go. Any other attempt to `create` or `build` sons for the parent will result in a missing `parent_id` in the `ParentSon` object.

With this association the `a.sons << b` approach is no way feasible.

Comment: yes, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-build-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is caused by you trying to set up the association when the objects have not yet been created (ie don't have an id yet).  What's happening is this

```
#make an unsaved (no id) Parent
a = Parent.new
#make an unsaved (no id) Son
b = Son.new

#try to make the association, by building a join table (ParentSon) record.  
a.sons << b

#the ParentSon object has neither a parent_id or a son_id, which is making it fail validation
a.valid?
=> false
```

If you want to make associations between objects that have not been created yet, you can use `.build` instead.  This will save the associated object when the parent when the parent is saved. eg

```
parent = Parent.new
son = parent.sons.build 
parent.save
```

Parent now has an id, son has an id, and the association should be made.  Both should be valid.  Try it.

Comment: That's not true. `a.parent_sons.first.son` has the correct value, while `a.parent_sons.first.parent` is empty. I would expect both to be nil or both to be valid.

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to add a son taken from an existing collection, so `parent.sons.build` is not the right choice for me.

Comment: Ok, a more general point is that if you try to make associations between objects which haven't been saved yet, then you're going to see unexpected behaviour.  Why not save them and then make the association?

Comment: In the case where you want to add an existing son to a parent, then build a parent_sons model instead:  `son = <some existing Son object>; parent  = Parent.new; parent.son_parents.build(:son => son)`

Comment: Sadly, even this approach will leave the `parent_id` field empty. Take a look at my own answer.

Comment: Why not save them before? Because I need to have at least one associated `Son` in my `Parent`.